# IIS 7, IPv4 address restriction when having multiple sites on the same server

Tags: iis-7, ip

I have one server running IIS 7 with two diffrent sites on the same port (80). They have different host header. 
On site 1 I would have no IP restrictions.
On site 2 I would like to alow only specified IP ranges.

How do I configure this in IIS? I found how to add IP address restrictions, but to me it seems like it is affecting both site 1 and site 2.

Answer (score 1):

Not in the side - you do so on the BINDING of the site (to IIS).

In the Binding you tell the hsot header and the IP addresses to bind to.

Comment: What I wanted was to only allow specified external IP ranges to access my site. Found my answer when I installed IP and Domain restrictions

Answer (score 1):

Why is it so that when you ask a question, you find the answer the next minute? :)
Anyway, I had not installed/activated IP and Domain restrictions.